# Display 2 products per row on mobile view in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website and I want to show 2 products per row on the **shope** page as well as on the **home**page when viewing the website on mobile or short screen. Write now it is only showing 1 product per row. Link to the website [www.obscot.com](http://obscot.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define your mobile width in CSS in your style.css and need to add the rule something like this

```
  @media(max-width:767px){
  .entry-content .products li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  }
  }
```

and it will look like this 
http://prntscr.com/f2uiq2
Thanks

Comment: How have you achieved it ? I tried your code in my CSS file and it is not working.

Comment: please add the CSS into the footer.php with opening and closing style tag

Comment: ok it worked but it only worked for my home page. If you navigate to shop page it is still showing 1 product per column. Can you please fix that also...

Comment: have you options to add custom CSS into your theme something, like customize options from theme, set it into admin end ? or try to add same code into your page.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143089/discussion-between-raj-kumar-bhardwaj-and-aseem-sharma).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f2uqas   shop page also working with 2 products per row.

Comment: Why this code is not working CSS file ? Why I have to paste that code into my footer.php ? I've never tried something like this

Comment: Yeah I know it is working because I found different solution on the internet

Comment: Can you please tell me why that code was supposed to be in footer.php ? Why it was not working in CSS file ?

Comment: because footer work for every file and its connected with each part of the website and the CSS file for mobile is different on your website which one you need to find from theme directories and paste the code into the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

First please check that the theme in your site is having facility to change it. If not then use below.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-change-products-per-row-based-on-screen-size/

Comment: I already know about this snippet. It is for desktop view only. I want to change product diplay when I view website on my mobile phone